# Remote control of camera between iphone and android?

Tags: iphone, applications, camera, remote-control, android

I am looking for an app that uses a smartphone to remotely control another smartphone's camera allowing me to see the perspective and zoom. It is technically possible. In fact I have found two apps, auto cam for itune and another camera app for android, to achieve it. The links are as below. Sorry I cannot find information in English. The link is in Chinese.

The problem is that it connects two iphones or two androids, but I need to connect between an iphone and an android. Does anyone know such a app?

Thank you!

[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.cloud95.android.cameraremoter&hl=zh_TW](http://phone97.com/?p=5352)

http://phone97.com/?p=5352

Comment: Could you please edit your question to clarify whether you want to use an iPhone to control an Android camera, or vice versa? Or do you want to be able to go both ways? And, if this is specific to a particular iPhone and Android device, it may be prudent to specify the exact models and versions of iOS and Android involved.

Comment: Thank you very much for your commend. Both ways will work for me.